# setStatusBarHidden and then how can I resize the application frame size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

If I use this method, isn't there someway to set the screen to the be the full 320x480 rather than the 320x460 it was before I hide the status bar?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in AppDelegate.m file

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

This code used for hide StatusBar. so u can get view size is 320 X 480 instead of 320 X 460.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your window is set to use [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] as it's frame, and setWantsFullScreenLayout on your very first view controller.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[viewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
[self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IB for storyboards or the more traditional way, make sure that the UIViewController settings for Status Bar is set to "None".  This will make sure that views you create and add to it will be the full size and not set to something smaller.

Also you will need to add an entry to the plist, called "Status bar is initially hidden" or UIStatusBarHidden and set that to YES.  This will stop the OS from showing the status bar for the application.

By doing these two things you can make sure you have the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I usually hide the status bar in the app delegate. Then whenever I need to create a new view controller I delete the UIView which comes with it. I add a new UIView onto the screen and set its size to 320 x 480 and connect it to the "view" outlet of the File's Owner. From my experience if the UIView is set to 320 x 460 and the status bar is hidden, then during run time the view gets stretched by 20 pixels. This causes a blurry effect on some of the subviews.